# Is it possible to display more than one image from a handler at the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, handler

The title says everithing, I have one Generic Handler(.ashx) and a I need to display one image at the same time using only one handler. Thank U!
I'm using asp.net and c# on my project.
All the images i need to display are generated dynamically.
I have one Web User Control, that use this handler to display the dynamically BitMap images created on a asp image control.
But when i use 2 of these WebControls at the same time, I have a problem because both WebControl display the same image.

ImageHandler.ashx (These effects doesn't really matters, it just changes the image when the user select the option on a dropdownlist, it's not the real problem.)

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string Effect = context.Request.QueryString["Effect"];
    if (Effect == "Normal")
    {
        Bitmap bmp = PanelStepTwo.image;
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        bmp.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
    else if (Effect == "PB")
    {
        Bitmap bmp = PanelStepTwo.imagePB;
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        bmp.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
    else if (Effect == "Sepia")
    {
        Bitmap bmp = PanelStepTwo.imageSepia;
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        bmp.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

Here it's, how the handler is called. (I is the index, beacause it's called on a loop)
Usuario.Imagens[i] returns a URL, for example, if the 'i' is 0, Usuario.Imagens[0] returns: @"http://edgeconstrutora.com.br/FotoFacil/Images/he0cy.png"

```
imgID = i;
var request = WebRequest.Create(Usuario.Imagens[i]);
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    image = new Bitmap(stream);
    var ratioX = (double)120 / image.Width;
    var ratioY = (double)120 / image.Height;
    var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);
    var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
    var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);
    proporcao = image.Width / newWidth;
    img.Width = newWidth;
    img.Height = newHeight;
    Effect = "Normal";
    img.ImageUrl = "ImageHandler.ashx?imgID=" + imgID + "&Effect=" + Effect.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Clarify what you mean by handler.  A handler could be a simple object which could return an array of images.  Your site would then display both images in whatever coordinates you want.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, I missed that, by handler i mean a Generic Handler, in my case it's called ImageHandler.ashx.
Edited my question, sorry about that, but what happens is, when i request the handler the second time, the firs image chenged to.

Comment: How are you calling the `Handler`?

Comment: It sounds like handler's response is just being cached. You could disable caching in the `context.Response` or have the UserControl that loads the image from the handler append a random query string to the url (like, today's date in seconds from unix epoc) as a cache buster.

Comment: Added             context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
            context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.MinValue);

To the top of my handler code and it dind't worked.
Dennis Rongo, i updated my question to show you how i'm calling the handler.

Comment: Where are you creating the `img` control (not be confused with your `image` Bitmap object) and what are you doing with it?  Looks to me like you are always changing the same image control, thus you will not see more than one image.  I think what you are after is to simply create a new image control for each request you make, then add it to the page's control hierarchy for display.

Comment: Jeremy, the img control was already created, like I said i'm using ONE img control for each Web User Control, the problem is when I use two Web Users Controls at the sime time. The img control is on my asp code of the WebUserControl. But whem i have 2 of these webusercontrols in one page, I need to display two different images at same time, and the problem is there. Got it?

Comment: Other way to solve it, is display Bitmap generated on the img control withou using handler, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Set the IsReusable property to true to handle multiple images. There is no MSDN documentation for this the last time I looked. But this is what I use for displaying say, a list of product images.

Comment: public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }


Not yet... the result was that the second image and the first were the same. The first one should be different.

Comment: how are you displaying them on the front end?

Comment: Yeah! I'm displaying it on a asp image control, the handler is used like a kind of a converter from Bitmap to asp img control. The only function of the handler is to display a Bitmap on img control. If u want i can send u the code, than it will be easyer to u, but i think u got it

Comment: Where u are setting width and height, comment out: //Effect = "Normal";

Comment: Are there any way to display bitmap without using thouse handlers...?

Comment: Look on the top of the page the second code shows: img.Width = newWidth;
            img.Height = newHeight;

Here i set de images widht and height, than i don't need to set it any more because img is the asp.net img control and after this I make no changes on it.